# Is models and schema the same in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm confused on after we do db:migrate, what does the schema means? Does it automatically change the models if they are connected or do we need to manually change the models to reflect the schema?

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about `db/schema.rb` file, it is not the same thing as a migration. The migration is designed to run database commands to update the actual underlying database schema.  When you run `rake db:migrate` it attempts to run any pending migrations on the database.  If successful, it will also under the hood run `rake db:schema:dump` which will update the `db/schema.rb` file which reflects the latest version of the actual schema. If for some reason the migration fails because of some error, it will rollback and leave the schema in its previous state to having run the migration.

The models in a Rails don't touch the schema itself, but there are generators the help you create a migration file.  For a better understanding of how all this works, you really should read through the [documentation here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

the `db/schema.rb` file represents the current configuration of the database, after any successful (or unsuccessful) migrations.

ActiveRecord uses `db/schema.rb` to 'automatically' configure attribute methods, for example if there's a `users` table with a column `first_name` then the `User` model will have a method `name` and a method `name=` as the getter and setter methods for that column.

You don't have to configure the models yourself, `ActiveRecord` does it all for you.

`ActiveRecord` also takes care of typecasting the variables as appropriate for the column defined in `db/schema.rb`.